# Is "the" essential in "The Book of Five Rings"?

Tags: grammaticality, redundancy

Is the word "the" in the title necessary? Would it make a difference if the title was "Book of Five Rings"? I've seen many "Book of ..." titles, both with and without "the", and I can't understand its purpose.

Answer (score 3):

**The** is there because the author chose that it should be there. Book titles are not subject to **any** rules of grammar **at all**. You may title a book whatever you want and you cannot be wrong.

Comment: And this being the case, questions about naming (eg books) are off-topic.

Comment: Only once the "rule" has been stated: prior to that, it was a valid question :)

Comment: No; questions about titles, most lyrics etc are off-topic precisely _because_ they don't follow standard rules, and analysis / acceptability debates become meaningless exercises.

Comment: Interesting: could you point me to that rule? It seems a little Alice in Wonderland; as (i) the OP did not know until he was told and (ii) if you close for that reason - which is off-topic - you answer his question.

Comment: But please, don’t ask any questions about the following topics. They are out of scope for this site....
Naming. [[ELU.Meta](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)] And [It seems that the overarching guideline is that questions should be objective enough that they can have a "correct" answer, to avoid being "Primarily Opinon Based."](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10256/to-what-extent-is-analyzing-poetry-or-verse-off-topic) This means an answer 'X is right', or 'X is wrong', not 'X can be anything, no matter how right- or wrong-looking, the author likes'. And this .

Comment: has appeared so many times on ELU. It's supposed to be a well-collated easily searchable repository of good English advice, not a series of repeated 'Standard rules do not apply at all here' statements. Titles, a lot of poetry and lyrics ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the link - It has clarified matters. it is not "off-topic" There is a difference between "It is a matter for the **author's opinion**", and "It is a matter of general opinion". The former closes the matter, the latter leave it open -- and leaving it open is to be avoided.

Comment: The grammar or lack of it, punctuation, choice of words ... are up to the author. So the question is only answerable by 'not a matter of standard English.' So off-topic. See [Stoney B's Answer here on ELU.Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3170/why-is-the-meaning-of-song-lyrics-off-topic), saying that such questions are off-topic. Off-topic questions should be CV-ed, not answered.

Comment: StoneyB's answer was, it appears, based solely on the fact that the verbs "get up" and "stand up" appear as lyrics. Were the same question put as "My teacher told me to get up, but told my friend to stand up. Is there a difference?" Would you have closed it? Could you please address "author's opinion" as an answer, and "general opinion" (see above) and discuss why you feel both are off-topic?